# facing a challenge writing my own and my_itoa and my atoi, which should change integer to ascii and vice versa in C

Tags: c, string, integer, embedded, ascii

I missed posting here, you always teach me a lot!

So, I have an assignment to write my own 2 functions to change from integer to ASCII and back from ASCII to integer for an embedded system, and they have very specific features:

here are the provided function definitions that I should build on. it is put in a data.h file:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t my_itoa(int32_t data, uint8_t * ptr, uint32_t base);

int32_t my_atoi(uint8_t * ptr, uint8_t digits, uint32_t base);
```

these functions should be used for basic data manipulation, here's how these functions are going to be used in another file course1.c which has data.c included:

```
digits = my_itoa( num, ptr, BASE_16);   
value = my_atoi( ptr, digits, BASE_16);
```

and:

```
digits = my_itoa( num, ptr, BASE_10);
value = my_atoi( ptr, digits, BASE_10);
```

there are certain features that should be in both functions:

1. they should support base 2 all the way to base 16.
2. string functions or libraries shouldn't be used.
3. All operations need to be performed using pointer arithmetic, not array indexing.
4. function needs to handle signed data.

for my_itoa:

1. Integer-to-ASCII needs to convert data from a standard integer type into an ASCII string.
2. The number you wish to convert is passed in as a signed 32-bit integer.
3. Copy the converted character string to the uint8_t* pointer passed in as a parameter (ptr)
4. The signed 32-bit number will have a maximum string size (Hint: Think base 2).
5. You must place a null terminator at the end of the converted c-string
6. Function should return the length of the converted data (including a negative sign). Example my_itoa(ptr, 1234, 10) should return an ASCII string length of 5 (including the null terminator).

for my_atoi:

1. ASCII-to-Integer needs to convert data back from an ASCII represented string into an integer type.
2. The character string to convert is passed in as a uint8_t * pointer (ptr).
3. The number of digits in your character set is passed in as a uint8_t integer (digits).
4. The converted 32-bit signed integer should be returned.

after my research into this thread: [Writing my own atoi function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429619/writing-my-own-atoi-function)

I was able to write this code, my data.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(){

        return 0;
}


uint8_t my_itoa(int32_t data, uint8_t * ptr, uint32_t base)
{
        return *ptr;
};


int32_t my_atoi(uint8_t * ptr, uint8_t digits, uint32_t base)
{
        const char* str= ptr;
        uint8_t len = strlen(str);
        str = (uint8_t*) malloc(len * sizeof(uint8_t));

        while (*str != '\0')
        {
                uint8_t a;
                a = *str -'0';
                *ptr = a;
                str++;
                ptr++;
        }
        str = str - len;
        ptr = ptr -len;

        return *ptr;
};
```

as I understand this part removes null character:

```
a = *str -'0';
```

this code has a main problem, which is when i compile it this way I get the in my_atoi that pointer differs in sginedness and pointer assignment differs in signedness:

```
src/data.c: In function ‘my_atoi’:
src/data.c:20:19: error: pointer targets in initialization differ in 
signedness [-Werror=pointer-sign]
  const char* str= ptr;
                   ^~~
src/data.c:22:6: error: pointer targets in assignment differ in 
signedness [-Werror=pointer-sign]
  str = (uint8_t*) malloc(len * sizeof(uint8_t));
      ^
```

and when I edit it to this:

```
uint8_t len = strlen(str);
```

I get errors that pointer target in passing argument 1 of strlen differ in sigdness, and in string.h strlen definition expected a const char*:

```
src/data.c: In function ‘my_atoi’:
src/data.c:21:19: error: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 
‘strlen’ differ in signedness [-Werror=pointer-sign]
  int len = strlen(str);
                   ^~~
In file included from src/data.c:3:0:
/usr/include/string.h:384:15: note: expected ‘const char *’ but 
argument is of type ‘unsigned char *’
extern size_t strlen (const char *__s)
              ^~~~~~
src/data.c:22:6: error: pointer targets in assignment differ in 
signedness [-Werror=pointer-sign]
  str = (char*) malloc(len * sizeof(char));
      ^
```

and also the fact that I need to get rid of strlen and string.h alltogether. like here: [Converting ASCII to Hex and vice versa - strange issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629899/converting-ascii-to-hex-and-vice-versa-strange-issue) so it was not very useful. Actually I don't understand the code inside of it.

Another challenge is with the determining input variable to function(3rd input) which should be BASE_10, BASE_16, or BASE_2 etc..., how should the variable:

```
uint32_t base
```

which is an int, store this value "BASE_10" to compare it in an if conditional? and what are the bases of conversion to different bases and how should I handle them?

I'm stuck on many different frontiers the answer to this challenge, where to learn more, what the requirement of maximum string size, how should I handle signed data. I'm seeking help. sorry for this long question but I needed to include all the factors.

---

EDIT editing this the code like this:

```
uint8_t* str= ptr;
uint8_t len = strlen((const char *)str);
```

following this thread:
[cast unsigned char * (uint8_t *) to const char *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009231/cast-unsigned-char-uint8-t-to-const-char?rq=1)

I have no errors now, but still need to completely get rid of string.h

Comment: You're starting from a bad/incorrect example. Use the second code block in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33438748/5382650 for `strtoi` as a guide

Comment: Note that the function definitions end at the `}` — the semicolon after the `}` is not needed, as it marks the end of an empty variable definition, or therebouts.

Comment: @ Craig: I don't really understand the code in that segment. would you clarify more.
@ Jonathan:which one exactly, because the compiler doesn't even give an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What?**

```
  str = (uint8_t*) malloc(len * sizeof(uint8_t));
  while (*str != '\0')
```

This `my_atoi()` code makes little sense.  Code allocates memory, whose contents are unknown  - then immediately tries to test them?

Memory allocation is not needed and then `strlen()` is not needed.

**Character to decimal value**

"I understand this part removes null character: `a = *str -'0';`" --> Not quite.  When `*str` is a digit character, `*str -'0'` converts the character encoded value (usually ASCII) to its numeric value (like 0 to 9).

`*str -'0'` is insufficient for hex digits like `'a'`, and `'F'`.

**Alternative**

Instead, iterate through `ptr` and scale a running sum.

The below does not meet 2 coding goals, which I leave for OP as sub-problems to handle.

** string functions or libraries shouldn't be used.
** function needs to handle signed data.

.

```
#include <ctype.h>

// Convert 1 digit
static int value(int ch) {
  if (isdigit(ch)) {
    return ch - '0';
  }
  if (isxdigit(ch)) {
    ch = tolower(ch);
    const char *xdigits = "abcdef";
    return strchr(xdigits, ch) - xdigits  + 10;
  }
  return INT_MAX; // non-digit
}

int32_t my_atoi(uint8_t * ptr, uint8_t digits, uint32_t base) {
  int32_t sum = 0;
  while (*ptr) {
    sum *= base;
    sum += value(*ptr++);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Better code would detect non-numeric input, overflow, no conversion, etc.  Other considerations not shown include handling a `'-'` sign, validating the base in range.

```
int32_t my_atoi(uint8_t * ptr, uint8_t digits, uint32_t base) {
  int32_t sum = 0;
  while (isspace(*ptr)) ptr++;  // skip leading white space
  if (*ptr == '+')  ptr++;      // Allow optional leading `+`
  bool digit_found = false;

  while (*ptr) {
    unsigned digit = value(*ptr++);
    if (digit >= base) {
      return INT_MIN; // TBD signal unexpected digit
    }
    if (sum >= INT_MAX/base && (sum > INT_MAX/base || digit > INT_MAX%base)) {
      // Overflow
      return INT_MIN; // TBD signal OF
    }
    sum *= base;
    sum += digit;
    digit_found = true;
  }

  if (*str) {
    sum = INT_MIN; // TBD signal unexpected junk at the end
  }
  if (!digit_found) {
    sum = INT_MIN; // TBD signal no digits
  }
  return sum;
}
```

**`my_itoa()`**

For help on `my_itoa()`, review [What is the proper way of implementing a good “itoa()” function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3440726/2410359).  It does have an nice answer in there [-](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29933810/2410359) somewhere.

Comment: I fixed the first error mentioned under what by doing this: 
`                uint8_t* str;
                uint8_t len = strlen((const char *)ptr);
                str = (uint8_t*) malloc(len * sizeof(uint8_t));
                *str = *ptr;
`
does this solve the problem?

and you posted two definitions for my_atoi(), i think I do not need the second one it is more perfect than what I will need.

so, for the first one, what is the function of the leading code?

Comment: @MahmoudSaad "function of the leading code" --> `value()` convert 1 `char` like `'1'`, `'8'`, `'a'`, `'F'`,  to 1,8,10,15.